# How to get binding expression of a datagrid column?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

How can I get the binding expression of a DataGrid column in WPF?

This is the XAML for the column:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="amountColumn" Header="Amount" Width="100"  
                    Binding="{Binding _Amount, StringFormat=c}" 
                    CellStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this code to get all binding expressions in a datagrid:

```
private Collection GetAllBindingsInDatagrid(DataGrid dg)
{
    Collection bindings = new Collection();
    if (dg.ItemsSource != null) {
        foreach (object item in dg.ItemsSource) {
            DataGridRow row = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            if (row != null) {
                foreach (BindingExpression binding in row.BindingGroup.BindingExpressions) {
                    bindings.Add(binding);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return bindings;
}
```

EDIT: Since the question was to get the "binding expression" of a column, which refers to a single instance of a binding, I thought the aim was to check if there's any validation errors or something, so the function above iterates the rows. But if the generic "binding" of the column itself is needed (e.g. in order to dynamically add a validation rule) this code could be used:

```
// first retrieve the Datagrid object as datagrid
DataGridTextColumn column = datagrid.FindName("amountColumn");
Binding binding = column.Binding;
```

Comment: It looks like you're going after rows. The OP wants the bindings of columns.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The `BindingExpression` objects are on the `TextBlock` elements, not on the column. First you need to get a cell. Then your can search for the inner `TextBlock`:

```
var textBlock = cell.FindFirstVisualChild<TextBlock>();
BindingExpression bindingExpression = textBlock.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty);
```

The code for `FindFirstVisualChild()`:

```
public static class DependencyObjectExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>([NotNull] this DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (dependencyObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dependencyObject));

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
            if (child is T o)
                yield return o;

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                yield return childOfChild;
        }
    }

    public static childItem FindFirstVisualChild<childItem>([NotNull] this DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        where childItem : DependencyObject
    {
        if (dependencyObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dependencyObject));

        return FindVisualChildren<childItem>(dependencyObject).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You use `BindingExpression`

```
BindingExpression bindingExpression = amountColumn.GetBindingExpression(DataGridTextColumn.BindingProperty);
```

Comment: sorry but DataGridTextColumn (amountColumn) dose not have a GetBindingExpression